# Arrange/Repeat Div From Right side To Left using CSS3

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I am developing website which support RTL. So I am repeating my div using foreach.

```
 <?php foreach ($list as $key => $row) { ?>
   <div>---contents---</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

as usual it is placing from left side to right side.

How can I make div repeating from left side to right side?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `dir` attribute. Something like this should work:

```
<dir dir="rtl">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</dir>
```

Add this bit of css to make sure the divs layout in a row:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[See the plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/xjuDswohQxP076jgv5s2?p=preview)

Comment: it is coming from right side to left, but nothing displaying inside row. there i have heading,description etc.

Comment: for simple div and content.. this will be solution.. but not for complex

Comment: Can you update your question? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You might be better off in this case to add  dir="rtl" to the top-level html element.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row-reverse` on the container element. This will have some additional effects which you even might have been looking for (position and size of child elements).

Or you put `float: right;` on all the child elements (and to be on the safe side, `overflow: hidden;` on the container, so that subsequent elements will be at the right vertical position)